# TypeError: include.model.getTableName is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

He thought there was a problem in the relationships between the tables. Each user can have at most one internship application.
However, when I want to access users from these applications, I encounter the  `TypeError: include.model.getTableName is not a function`   problem, I still haven't solved it.
I have to combine 2 models with each other.

**User model**

```
 const User = sequelize.define('user', {

    mail: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: {
        args: true,
        msg: 'Bu mail adresi kullanılmaktadır !',
      },
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Bu alan boş bırakılamaz !',
        },
        isEmail: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Kurallara uygun mail adresi giriniz !',
        },
      }
    },

    password: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
      validate: {
        len: {
          args: [8, 64],
          msg: 'Şifre en az 8 karakterden oluşabilir.'
        },
      }
    }


  }, {
    tableName: "users",

  });


  User.associate = (models) => {

    User.hasOne(models.userrole, {
      as: 'userroles',
      foreignKey: 'userID'
    });
   User.belongsTo(models.internship, {
      as: 'internships',
      foreignKey: 'id'
    });
  };
```

**Internship model**

```
 const Internship = sequelize.define('internship', {

    userID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    userInfoID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    schoolInfoID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    privateInfoID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    statusID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    
    },
  }, {
    tableName: "internships"
  });

  Internship.associate = (models) => {

    Internship.belongsTo(models.user, {
      as: 'users',
      foreignKey: 'userID'
    });
  };
```

**Controller**

```
     internship.findAll({ 
            include: [
            {
                as:"users",
                model: user,
            
            },
            ]
        }).then(result=>{
            res.status(200).json({
                result })
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined any primary key in your Internship model and user model and also there is model spell mistake in associations .

```html
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id:{ 
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    mail: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: {
        args: true,
        msg: 'Bu mail adresi kullanılmaktadır !',
      },
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Bu alan boş bırakılamaz !',
        },
        isEmail: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Kurallara uygun mail adresi giriniz !',
        },
      }
    },

    password: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
      validate: {
        len: {
          args: [8, 64],
          msg: 'Şifre en az 8 karakterden oluşabilir.'
        },
      }
    }


  }, {
    tableName: "users",

  });


  User.associate = (models) => {

    User.hasOne(models.userrole, {
      as: 'userroles',
      foreignKey: 'userID'
    });
   User.belongsTo(models.Internship, {
      as: 'internships',
      foreignKey: 'id'
    });
  };
```

**Internship model**

```html
const Internship = sequelize.define('internship', {
    id:{ 
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    userID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    userInfoID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    schoolInfoID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    privateInfoID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    statusID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    
    },
  }, {
    tableName: "internships"
  });

  Internship.associate = (models) => {

    Internship.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: 'users',
      foreignKey: 'userID'
    });
  };
```

**Controller**

```html
     Internship.findAll({ 
            include: [
            {
                as:"users",
                model: User,
            
            },
            ]
        }).then(result=>{
            res.status(200).json({
                result })
        })
```